# Java weird compilation error with guava CharMatcher.matchesAnyOf

Tags: java, compiler-errors, guava

In my java project, I have the following line of code:

```
CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.matchesAnyOf("string");
```

This line works perfectly in eclipse (Windows, Guava 14.0.1, Java 1.6.0_22-b04). When compiling on our integration VM (debian, Guava 14.0.1 Java 1.6.0_22-b04), the line produces the following error:

```
[javac] /opt/quantis/src/Quantis_EJB/ejbModule/internals/QtsSessionManagerBean.java:298: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method matchesAnyOf(java.lang.String)
[javac] location: class com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
[javac]         CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.matchesAnyOf("string");
```

It's not a classpath issue, as other lines requiring guava 14 features works well. Following lines produces no error:

```
CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.matchesNoneOf("string");
Hashing.sha512().newHasher().putString("string");
```

Any idea about why just this symbol and not the other are not resolved? Spcific bug in linux JDK? Conflicts with other potential jar in my classpath (we have a lot of other dependancies)?

Comment: Are you using Maven? If so, what does `mvn dependency:tree` show?

Comment: Sadly, still no maven for this old project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use Maven, you might be managing your dependencies manually. In that case, have you tried simply greping all your dependencies to find in which jars the class exists?

```
grep -E com.google.common.base.CharMatcher lib/*
```

It also works if your build process bundles something containing the dependencies, the important is to have them all in one place.

The other option is to find out where the class comes from programatically, from the runtime. If you comment out the offending line to be able to compile and you can run it in some way (unit test or other), you can find out the origin of the class using the following code:

```
System.out.println(CharMatcher.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation())
```

The offender could be an old Google Collections jar, the predecessor of Guava, if it had `CharMatcher` (the "Since 1.0" seems to indicate it), or another jar embedding the Guava classes.

Comment: I don't think Google Collections had a `CharMatcher` class.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Right, I forgot about the specific problem when writing that line.

Comment: At runtime the right jar is used. I greped the whole integration VM and only one jar holds an old version of guava (without the matchesAnyOf() method, introduced in guava 8). The strange part is that this jar should not and seems not to be in the compilation classpath. But this is the only coherent explanation, so I guess we will use a workaround until we move to maven. Thanks!